# Issue while fetching the List of file attachments in mail with Graph API

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to pull out the information around the file attachments in the mail in graph explorer , i have tried using it with every file type but it is specifically not working with Microsoft word documents which is around (30 MB).

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{mail-id}/messages/{message-id}/attachments](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bmail-id%7D/messages/%7Bmessage-id%7D/attachments)

In this link it is able to get the message from the message ID , but while adding "/attachments" at the end of the link it is getting timeout .

Answer (score 0):

You can select the properties you need, so you can avoid downloading the whole content of the attachment.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{mail-id}/messages/{message-id}/attachments/?$select=id,name,contentType](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bmail-id%7D/messages/%7Bmessage-id%7D/attachments/?$select=id,name,contentType)

Code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var attachments = await graphClient.Users["{mail-id}"].Messages["{message-id}"].Attachments
    .Request()
    .Select("id,name,contentType")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: As i need to extract the contentBytes of the attachment , it is reflecting with with the error           Errror:
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'contentBytes' on type 'microsoft.graph.attachment'.",

Comment: Can you get the detailed error info (including timestamp requestid) for the analysis?